# covert raw mysql query to yii2 query 2 left join subquery and sum all

Tags: yii2

I have created a raw query in mysql which is working fine. I am trying to convert it to yii2 query but I can't complete it Can anyone help me

Raw query:

```
SELECT
  ship.month_name,
  MIN(ship.average_value_percent) as minimum_container_utilization,
  MAX(ship.average_value_percent) as maximum_container_utilization,
  SUM(ship.average_value) / COUNT(ship.shipment) as volume,
  SUM(ship.average_weight) / COUNT(ship.shipment) as volume_kgs,
  SUM(ship.average_volume_cbm) / COUNT(ship.shipment) as volume_cbm,
  SUM(ship.average_value_percent) / COUNT(ship.shipment) as volume_percent
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      sh.JS_UniqueConsignRef as shipment,
      SUM(sp.volume) as average_volume_cbm,
      SUM(sp.volume) / SUM(sc.teu) AS average_value,
      SUM(sp.volume) / SUM(sc.capacity) AS average_value_percent,
      SUM(sp.weight) as average_weight,
      date_format(sh.JS_E_ARV, '%b') AS month_name,
      if(
        month(sh.JS_E_ARV) >= month(now()),
        month(sh.JS_E_ARV),
        month(sh.JS_E_ARV) + 12
      ) as months_order
    FROM
      ship_head sh
      JOIN (
        SELECT
          SUM(RC_TEU) teu,
          SUM(RC_Cubiccapacity) capacity,
          ship_head_id,
          JC_ContainerMode,
          JC_ContainerNum
        FROM
          ship_container
        GROUP BY
          ship_head_id,
          JC_ContainerNum,
          JC_ContainerMode
      ) sc ON sc.ship_head_id = sh.sh_id
      JOIN (
        SELECT
          SUM(JL_ActualVolume) volume,
          SUM(JL_ActualWeight) weight,
          ship_head_id,
          JC_ContainerNum
        FROM
          ship_pack
        GROUP BY
          ship_head_id,
          JC_ContainerNum
      ) sp ON sp.ship_head_id = sh.sh_id
    WHERE
      sh.is_latest = 1
      AND sp.JC_ContainerNum = sc.JC_ContainerNum
      AND sc.JC_ContainerMode IN ('FCL', 'FTL')
      AND sh.JS_E_ARV < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      and sh.JS_E_ARV > Date_add(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, interval - 12 month)
    GROUP BY
      sh.sh_id
  ) AS ship
GROUP BY
  ship.month_name,
  ship.months_order
ORDER BY
  ship.months_order
```

Yii2 query

```
$shipContainerQuery = ShipContainer::find()
    ->select(['SUM(RC_TEU) AS teu' ,'SUM(RC_Cubiccapacity) AS capacity', 'ship_head_id', 'JC_ContainerMode', 'JC_ContainerNum'])
    ->groupBy('ship_head_id', 'JC_ContainerNum', 'JC_ContainerMode')
    ->all();

    $shipPackQuery = ShipPack::find()
    ->select(['UM(JL_ActualVolume) AS volume', 'SUM(JL_ActualWeight) AS weight', 'ship_head_id', 'JC_ContainerNum'])
    ->groupBy('ship_head_id', 'JC_ContainerNum')
    ->all();

    $shipHeadQuery = ShipHead::find()
    ->select(['sh.JS_UniqueConsignRef AS shipment', 'SUM(sp.volume) AS average_volume_cbm', 'SUM(sp.volume) / SUM(sc.teu) AS average_value', 'SUM(sp.volume) / SUM(sc.capacity) AS average_value_percent', 'SUM(sp.weight) AS average_weight', 'date_format(sh." . $filterField . ",'%b') AS month_name', 'if(month(sh." . $filterField . ")>=month(now()), month(sh." . $filterField . "), month(sh." . $filterField . ")+12) as months_order)'])
    ->from(ShipHead::tableName() .' AS sh')
    ->leftJoin(['sc' => $shipContainerQuery], "sc.ship_head_id = sh.sh_id AND sc.JC_ContainerMode IN ('FCL', 'FTL')")
    ->leftJoin(['sp' => $shipPackQuery],'sp.ship_head_id = sh.sh_id AND sp.JC_ContainerNum = sc.JC_ContainerNum')
    ->where(['sh.is_latest' => 1])
    ->andWhere('sh.JS_E_ARV < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH and sh.JS_E_ARV > Date_add(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,interval - 12 month)')
    ->groupBy('sh.sh_id');

    $shipQuery = $shipQuery
    ->addSelect(["SUM(ship.average_value) / COUNT(ship.shipment) AS volume", "'teu' as volume_unit", "SUM(ship.average_value_percent) / COUNT(ship.shipment) AS average_container_utilization"])
```

Comment: Could you please show the output of `$shipQuery->createCommand()->sql`

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is, that you are calling `all()` method in your subqueries. Thanks to that, you are passing the results of them into the other query instead of passing them as query.

The other problem is that in your php code you are using `leftJoin` but in your raw SQL you have `JOIN` which means `INNER JOIN`.

You need to use arrays when specifing multiple columns by `groupBy()`.

You might want to wrap the more complex expressions in `\yii\db\Expression` instance to prevent Yii from messing your expression when attempting to quote table names or columns.

You can also add alias to ActiveQuery by using `$shipHeadQuery->alias('sh')` instead of `$shipHeadQuery->from(ShipHead::tableName() .' AS sh')`.

You can use arrays to specify the alias for selected columns for better readability.

The whole query might look like this

```php
//Add following two lines to the other use clauses if they are not already there.
use \yii\db\Expression; 
use \yii\db\Query;

$shipContainerQuery = ShipContainer::find()
    ->select([
        'teu' => new Expression('SUM(RC_TEU)'),
        'capacity' => new Expression('SUM(RC_Cubiccapacity)'),
        'ship_head_id',
        'JC_ContainerMode',
        'JC_ContainerNum',
    ])->groupBy(['ship_head_id', 'JC_ContainerNum', 'JC_ContainerMode']);

$shipPackQuery = ShipPack::find()
    ->select([
        'volume' => new Expression('SUM(JL_ActualVolume)'),
        'weight' => new Expression('SUM(JL_ActualWeight)'),
        'ship_head_id',
        'JC_ContainerNum',
    ])->groupBy(['ship_head_id', 'JC_ContainerNum']);

$shipHeadQuery = ShipHead::find()
    ->select([
        'shipment' => 'sh.JS_UniqueConsignRef',
        'average_volume_cbm' => new Expression('SUM(sp.volume)'),
        'average_value' => new Expression('SUM(sp.volume) / SUM(sc.teu)'),
        'average_value_percent' => new Expression('SUM(sp.volume) / SUM(sc.capacity)'),
        'average_weight' => new Expression('SUM(sp.weight)'),
        'month_name' => new Expression("date_format(sh.JS_E_ARV, '%b')"),
        'months_order' => new Expression('if(month(sh.JS_E_ARV) >= month(now()),  month(sh.JS_E_ARV),month(sh.JS_E_ARV) + 12)'),
    ])->alias('sh')
    ->innerJoin(['sc' => $shipContainerQuery], 'sc.ship_head_id = sh.sh_id')
    ->innerJoin(['sp' => $shipPackQuery], 'sp.ship_head_id = sh.sh_id')
    ->where(['sh.is_latest' => 1])
    ->andWhere('sp.JC_ContainerNum = sc.JC_ContainerNum')
    ->andWhere(['in', 'sc.JC_ContainerMode', ['FCL', 'FTL']])
    ->andWhere(new Expression('sh.JS_E_ARV < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH'))
    ->andWhere(new Expression('sh.JS_E_ARV > Date_add(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, interval - 12 month)')
    ->groupBy('sh.sh_id');

$shipQuery = new Query()
    ->select([
        'ship.month_name',
        'minimum_container_utilization' => new Expression('MIN(ship.average_value_percent)'),
        'maximum_container_utilization' => new Expression('MAX(ship.average_value_percent)'),
        'volume' => new Expression('SUM(ship.average_value) / COUNT(ship.shipment)'),
        'volume_kgs' => new Expression('SUM(ship.average_weight) / COUNT(ship.shipment)'),
        'volume_cbm' => new Expression('SUM(ship.average_volume_cbm) / COUNT(ship.shipment)'),
        'volume_percent' => new Expression('SUM(ship.average_value_percent) / COUNT(ship.shipment)'),
    ])->from(['ship' => $shipHeadQuery])
    ->groupBy(['ship.month_name', 'ship.months_order'])
    ->orderBy(['ship.months_order' => SORT_ASC]);
```

Then you can get the results by calling `$shipQuery->all()` or you can use the query where you need.

---

Because I don't have the DB structure I didn't test the query. There might be some typos or the query might need some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just using DAO to remove complexity, converting to yii2 query is not a good idea.